# fullPage.js skips sections when scrolling fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I have a normal scroll section at the top of the page which has some parallax effects and below it there are more standard animated **fullPage.js** sections.

It works really great but the problem I have is when I **do a fast scrolling** from top of the page. It skips second section and maybe the third, depending how fast mouse wheel is fired.

It's very bad user experience especially when using Apple's magic mouse, but issue occurs with any type of mouse.

I guess the problem is because of normal scroll section at the top, but I don't know how to solve it. Does anybody has the idea on how this could be solved?

Here is the link: http://2016.macleo.de

P.S. I have also added an onLeave callback with scrollTop animation triggering manually but still buggy. I can see third section a little when trying to scroll fast through site, like some users would probably do.

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    var leavingSection = $(this);

    //after leaving section 1
    if(index == 1 && nextIndex == 2 && direction =='down') {
        $("html,body").stop().animate({scrollTop:$(window).height()});
    }
}
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Can you explain how have you created the "normal" section at the top? 
Fullpage.js does not provide anyway to do it, so it seems the problem is in your side.

Comment: I have done initialization with option:
`normalScrollElements: '.section#parallax'` 
and that's it.

Comment: normalScrollElements is not suppose to be used in a whole section, hence your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So it's impossible to make this to work better or achieve the same effect with different approach?